# Localizing Error Messages In ASP.NET MVC 2 (Default Validation Attributes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, localization

i'm working on a multi language website and i want to localize the validation error messages for most of the ValidationAttribute such as `[Requried]`

I know it can be done as [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com) have shown in this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/12/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx).

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), 
ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
```

but i want to to customize the error message the way i did with my custom Validation Attributes in here :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property,
                                     AllowMultiple = false,
                                     Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateminRequiredNonalphanumericCharactersAttribute
: ValidationAttribute
{

    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = // Message From Resource Here ( i will be using two variables in this message ) 
    private readonly int _minnonalphanumericCharactersCounter = Membership.Provider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters;

    public ValidateminRequiredNonalphanumericCharactersAttribute()
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
            ErrorMessageString, name, _minnonalphanumericCharactersCounter);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string valueAsString = value as string;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString))
            return false;

        int nonalphanumericCharactersCounter = 0;
        char[] password = valueAsString.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            if (!char.IsNumber(c) && !char.IsLetter(c))
                nonalphanumericCharactersCounter++;
        }

        return (nonalphanumericCharactersCounter >= _minnonalphanumericCharactersCounter);
    }
}
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how it's done. it's really simple and straight.

What i did is that I created my own custom `RequiredAttribute`. instead of using the built in `RequiredAttribute`.

The only down side is that you will need to implement the logic of that validator by yourself.

I know some might think it's an over head to re-implement something that is already there. (reinventing the wheel) but this way I will have full control over the Validator logic and error message.

As you can see the logic is implemented in the `IsValid()` Method below.

Here's the  RequiredAttribute class that I've created :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, 
                                         AllowMultiple = true, 
                                         Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = // Error Message
    // Notice that i can include the filed name in the error message 
    // which will be provided in the FormatErrorMessage Method 

    public RequiredAttribute()
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString,
            name);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(value)))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

now when it comes to using the Validator you will need to provide the full reference of your new class as it will collide with the default built in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute` class in my example above.

in my case this is what the final results looks like :

```
    [Amaly.Data.Validators.Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

Hope this was useful.

Comment: After you pointed me to this answer I copied your code and included it in my app then later found out there's a nasty bug in it (it took me hours to figure out why the validation with my custom attribute was *strange*. The error is in IsValid() method. This method should contain this:    if (value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) {
    return false;
   }
   return true;

Comment: please correct it for other's sake. The point is to remove the as string casting cause its problematic with various value types.

Comment: @mare Thanks for fixing my buggy code ,,, I guess I didn't have this issue bcoz I used my Validator with primitive types only.