# Easiest way to alter required validation message site wide

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to replace validation message for all model properties that have `[Required]` attribute from the default "The XY field is required." to "*". I want to do that site wide in one place without having to add a custom message to `Required` attributes or passing additional parameter to ValidationMessageFor() Html helper.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer to my question here :

[Localizing Error Messages In ASP.NET MVC 2 (Default Validation Attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541107/localizing-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-2-default-validation-attributes)